# CMIS document repository

Tags: pdf, download, upload, cmis, cmis-workbench

I am so lost. So, a couple of years ago i did a WS for a client, to download and upload PDF files, now he is asking me if it can be use or if it can be changed in order for the PDF files be accessible to a "CMIS" frontend.

i have been searching the web for a couple of days now and i cant find any info on my problem, theres a lot of info on the cliente side and on how to connect and work with CMIS repositories but not in how to make a normal repository into a CMIS repository.

How can i make the PDF files accessible to the CMIS Cliente frontend?

Am i just big mess and not saying anything that makes sense?

thanks

Comment: What language is your server written in? That'll make a big difference on what (if anything) you should do

Comment: Check out the CMIS sever development guide (Java): https://github.com/cmisdocs/ServerDevelopmentGuide

Comment: thx for directions guys.  its an windows server with an SQL data base

Comment: thx for directions guys. it's an normal windows server with an SQL database that contains the important information and the location of the PDF files. my last coment wasnt finished i pressed enter :-P